# converters for python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt data where columns 6 and 7 are GPS position in the form:

```
50;18.5701400N,4;07.7693770E
```

When I read it by read_csv I try to convert it to cartesian coordinates by using converters. I wrote the function for converter

```
convertFunc = lambda x : float((x[0:5]+x[6:12]).replace(';','.'))
convert = {6:convertFunc,7:convertFunc}
```

when I use it on single value it works how I would like:

```
convertFunc(myData.Lat[1])
Out [159]:  55.187110250000003
```

when I try to use it in read_csv it does not work

```
myData = DataFrame(read_csv('~/data.txt', sep=',' names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Lat', 'Long'],converters=convert))
```

I have an error:

```
...
convertFunc = lambda x : float((x[0:5] + x[6:12]).replace(';', '.'))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): DGPS ongitu
```

I don't know where do it wrong or what I misunderstand in converters?
Or maybe anyone knows good way (package) to work with GPS data in that form?

(I think it can be some problem with `lambda` When I want to apply my function to the column  I have an error: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert the *header row*...try leaving off `names=` so that `read_csv` gets the column names from the header row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed `names=` but it does not change, have the same error.

Comment: Hmm, try `skiprows=1`? Maybe post a sample of your `data.txt` so it's clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That converter is a bit hacky; might I recommend something more robust like this?

```
def convert_dmds(s):
    deg, min = s[:-1].split(';')
    sign = 1 if s[-1] in 'NE' else -1
    return sign * (float(deg) + float(min) / 60.0)

def convert_gps(s):
    lat, lon = s.split(',')
    return (convert_dmds(lat), convert_dmds(lon))
```

Also, the error indicates that you are trying to convert something that is clearly not a GPS string -- a header row, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your converter is not ok.

```
In [67]: convertFunc = lambda x : float((x[0:5]+x[6:12]).replace(';','.'))

In [68]: convertFunc('4;07.7693770E')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 4.07.693770
```

On top of a dodgy converter, i think you apply the converter to the wrong column (look at the exception you get).